# Use "keras code" (Tensorflow) and the result is "loss: nan"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

requirements.txt

```
absl-py==2.0.0
astunparse==1.6.3
cachetools==5.3.1
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
flatbuffers==23.5.26
gast==0.4.0
google-auth==2.23.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.58.0
h5py==3.9.0
idna==3.4
keras==2.13.1
libclang==16.0.6
Markdown==3.4.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
numpy==1.24.3
oauthlib==3.2.2
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.1
pandas==2.1.1
protobuf==4.24.3
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
tensorboard==2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.1
tensorflow==2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.13.0
tensorflow-intel==2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
termcolor==2.3.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==1.26.16
Werkzeug==2.3.7
wrapt==1.15.0
```

I am using this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

# csv load
csv_file = 'point.csv'

# df change
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# df numpy change
sampledata = df.to_numpy()

# a, b columns
a = sampledata[:, [0, 1]]
b = sampledata[:, 2]

# print(np.array(a))
# print(np.array(b))

a_data = np.array(a)
b_data = np.array(b)

print("===============")

print('x', a.shape, 'y', b.shape)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2, ), activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=1e-2), loss='mse')

model.summary()

hist = model.fit(a, b, epochs=1000)

# result print
 
csv_file = 'point_copy.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
sampledata = df.to_numpy()

a = sampledata[:, [0, 1]]

a_data = np.array(a)

result = model.predict(a_data)

print(result)
```

I saw result error:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 3

=================================================================
Total params: 3 (12.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 3 (12.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/1000
27/27 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/1000
27/27 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/1000
27/27 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
```

Please tell me what the problem.

point.csv

| date | time | point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1216 | 1811412 | 8142211 |
| 1217 | 1911531 | 7511721 |
| 1218 | 1015230 | 5689431 |

~**842 Lines**

point_copy.csv

| date | time | point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1216 | 1626282 |  |
| 1217 | 1936261 |  |
| 1218 | 1243600 |  |
| 1218 | 1242400 |  |

Maybe is data too big a problem?

Comment: which version of keras are you using? That would make it easier to reproduce. Also check your imports, in your example you are not importing pandas, but you are using pd. Further it would make it easier if you would provide the csv file, or at least a minimal version of your csv file to copy paste, so the file can be scaffolded on our side. Thanks

Comment: keras version 2.13.1
and 7-8-digit random data for each of the 842 lines

Comment: Did you check your data for outliers or missing values (describe/info)?

Comment: Should I remove outliers?, Missing values do not exist

Comment: If you are randomly generating your training data, there shouldn't be hurtful outliers by definition. Or your random generation is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue of encountering a loss of NaN during training often arises
> due to numerical instability. Neural networks are sensitive to the
> scale of input data and the learning rate.

Sources [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-improve-neural-network-stability-and-modeling-performance-with-data-scaling/), and a book that I can recommend for sanity checking your neural network training [here](https://amzn.eu/d/asNmTti) - especially if you want to familiarize yourself with these kind of hickups in neural network training.

**Normalizing the Data**

Normalize or scale your input features to be within a similar range, such as [0, 1] or [-1, 1]. This can be done using Min-Max scaling or Standardization. Which makes your neural network more robust, especially when using bare metal stochastic gradient descent.

A next step would then be to opt for another optimizer, e.g. ADAM, which does account a little to prohibit [exploding gradients](https://karpathy.medium.com/yes-you-should-understand-backprop-e2f06eab496b).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
a_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(a)
```

Or alternatively just scale programmatically without another package

```
# Scale the features using Min-Max scaling
a_scaled = (a - a.min(axis=0)) / (a.max(axis=0) - a.min(axis=0))
```

For everyone else coming here, this is how I randomly generate the data:

```
# Data for 'date' column (assuming 842 rows)
    dates = np.arange(1216, 1216 + 842)

    # Generate random 7-8 digit numbers for 'tomato' and 'phone' columns
    tomato = np.random.randint(10 ** 6, 10 ** 8, size=len(dates))
    phone = np.random.randint(10 ** 6, 10 ** 8, size=len(dates))

    # Create a DataFrame
    data = {
        'date': dates,
        'tomato': tomato,
        'phone': phone
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Extract features and labels
    a = df[['date', 'tomato']].values
    b = df['phone'].values
```

Scaling did the trick:

[image: Sclaing did the trick]

Comment: I'll try it later and leave a comment if I have any questions

Comment: So I made it run, and scaling did the trick, you are welcome.

Comment: Thank you.  I think the results come out differently when I use it by changing various algorisms.